# Disk very slow after going from 9.04 to 10.04

Tags: disk

My disk is very slow after I installed ubuntu 10.04 over my old 9.04. Doing some tinkering helped a little:

> ```
> sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda1
>
> /dev/sda1:
> Timing cached reads: 3668 MB in 2.00 seconds = 1834.11 MB/sec
> Timing buffered disk reads: 292 MB in 3.02 seconds = 96.83 MB/sec
>
> sudo hdparm -c1 -d1 -X 66 /dev/sda1
>
> /dev/sda1:
> setting 32-bit IO_support flag to 1
> HDIO_SET_32BIT failed: Invalid argument
> setting using_dma to 1 (on)
> HDIO_SET_DMA failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
> setting xfermode to 66 (UltraDMA mode2)
> HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(setxfermode) failed: Invalid exchange
> IO_support = 0 (default)
> HDIO_GET_DMA failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>
>
> sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda1
>
> /dev/sda1:
> Timing cached reads: 4006 MB in 2.00 seconds = 2003.29 MB/sec
> Timing buffered disk reads: 312 MB in 3.02 seconds = 103.41 MB/sec
> ```

But it is still far too slow. On the other version, I had a custom partition setup, with the home partition with 100GB, and ext3 (and other partitions for swap, boot, root folder and space for a windows partition I never cared to install ).

This time I am using a standard Lynx setup (2 partitions, the swap and the main one with almost 250Gb, using ext4).

Some applications I develop, that use disk for some unit tests, are now very slow to work with. Is there a way to making it faster? Going back to 9.04? Waiting for 10,10? Gparting and making partitions smaller on ext3? I don't know if any of these will work....

Comment: That already seems quite fast for a hard disk. Mine is slower and my Lucid runs great. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Maybe it is just the way sqlite3 interact with ext4 (badly). On this discussion on datamapper group (http://groups.google.com/group/datamapper/browse_thread/thread/4481d51dcb97b073#) I mention how this affected a friend of mine, working on the same project, who, after a ubuntu update, had his disk also slowed down to a crawl.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it has to do with a bad kernel issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1039476

I'll try later installing a server kernel to see if it solves the issue.

Edit: Actually older kernels still do have this issue. Maybe a server kernel?